# Grid 8x8 on javascript with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, newline

I'm trying to write a grid that look like this:

[8x8 grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v8tS.png)

As you could realize there's an empty space ' ' before every '#'.
I got this so far:

```js
function myfunction() {

  cols = 8;
  rows = 8;
  board = [];


  for (i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= rows; j++) {
      console.log(board[i][j] = '#');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure in what I'm wrong, please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never define anything in `board`, which results in a TypeError (you can't access board[i][j]. You can throw away the `board` variable entirely and just print the board with `cols` and `rows`, and by adding to a string variable to display:

```js
function myfunction(){
  let cols = 7;
  let rows = 7;
  let displayStr= '';
  for(let i = 0; i<=cols; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j<=rows; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) displayStr += '#';
      else displayStr += ' ';
    }
    displayStr += '\n';
  }
  console.log(displayStr);
}
myfunction();
```

Comment: Oh my god, I had no idea of what 'let' is. Also I thought I had to use arrays on this, but you did it in a pretty much easier way, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Is there a way I can give you a vote, a star or something? this helped me a lot.

Comment: Using `let` (or `const`, which is preferable, or `var`) when declaring variables means you create proper local scoped variables - when you declare them *without* an identifier, you're implicitly creating global variables, which is something to be avoided at all costs. When you see answers that answer your question or are useful, you can upvote them (press the upward-pointing triangle) and Accept them as the right answer if you're the asker.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got only one question, on this part: if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) displayStr += '#';
      else displayStr += ' ';
    }
    displayStr += '\n';
  }  Why are you making a plus betwen 'i' and 'j' ?

Comment: That's what enables the lines to have the '#' starting on alternating indicies (0 and 1). See what happens when you take it out